# Problem executing Makefile for FPGA poject-Vivado

Tags: makefile, vivado

Hi I am new to creating makefile.
I have written the following commands in a makefile but they do not seem to execute when i type make in my terminal.
However, if i type the command separately in the terminal, it works.

I am trying to open a vivado project in this tcl file and do some spyglass analysis on it and save the result in a txt file.The tcl file also runs properly if executed separately.
I cd to my project folder where all the files- sources folder, project folder, makefile is present. I named it "makefile" so that i can execute it by typing make in the terminal.The makefile contents are as follows.

```
.PHONY : vivado_open 
vivado_open:
    $(info Hello Make)
    bsub -Is -q i_soc_rh7 -R "rusage[mem=32000, temp=1GB] affinity[core(8):membind=localonly]" vivado -nolog -nojou -mode batch -source vivado.tcl
```

Here is the result from the terminal

```
$make 
Hello Make 
make: Nothing to be done for `vivado_open'.
```

Comment: What happens when you type make?  What did you name the makefile?  What directory are you in when you type make?

Comment: @MadScientist  directory contains: as my sources and project file, name the file it as makefile, it displays the info and next line it says make: Nothing to be done for 'target'.

Comment: Add vivado_open to a phony target. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html  And reconsider the use (or abuse) of a makefile for this.

Comment: @vermaete..I tried that..it still gives me the following $make 
Hello Make
make: Nothing to be done for `vivado_open'.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the information requested, via cut and paste of actual output not paraphrasing, rather than putting it in comments: it's not possible to correctly format comments and with makefiles a LOT of the issues (for people new to it) are related to formatting.  It is not possible for you to get the result you say, given the makefile you show here.  Is the line `$(info Hello Make)` indented with a hard TAB, or with spaces?  What exact change did you make to use phony (please update your question)?  Do you have a file or directory named `vivado_open` in your directory?

Comment: @MadScientist done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but there has to be something else going on here, that you haven't told us about.  It's simply not possible for you to get that output if you typed `make` with that makefile.

You are using a variable, not a target named `vivado_open`, so make would *never* print *nothing to be done for 'vivado_open'.*  It would say instead something like: *nothing to be done for ../projectfiles/test.prj*

Further, you didn't answer my question about TABs vs. spaces.  If both the `info` and `bsub` lines are indented with TABs, there's no possible way that make would print `Hello Make`, without *also* printing the `bsub` command and trying to run it.

You must have another makefile in your directory, maybe named `Makefile` or `GNUmakefile`, that is being used instead of `makefile`.  Or maybe you have an environment variable like `MAKEFILES` set which is causing other makefiles to be read.

If none of those appear to be true, you'll have to run `make -d` and see if you can figure out what's happening.  That output is far too large to post to StackOverflow, so you'll have to try to read it yourself.

**EDITED**

OK, the problem is you're using spaces to indent your rules.  In make, all recipe lines must be indented with a hard TAB character.  Normal spaces don't mean anything special to make.  Basically your makefile is interpreted as if you'd written this:

```
.PHONY : vivado_open 
vivado_open:
$(info Hello Make)
bsub -Is -q i_soc_rh7 -R "rusage[mem=32000, temp=1GB] affinity[core(8):membind=localonly]" vivado -nolog -nojou -mode batch -source vivado.tcl
```

This is why you get this message "nothing to be done": you haven't actually defined a recipe for `vivaldo_open`, so there is literally nothing that make knows to do to update that target.

As an aside, normally you would get a syntax error for the `bsub` line because make doesn't know what that is.  However, if you look carefully at your line you'll see that it contains a `:`.  So, make is interpreting this as a set of targets and set of prerequisites, like this:

```
bsub ... affinity[core(8)  :  membind=localonly]" vivado ... vivado.tcl
```

(make doesn't care about quotes or other special characters like `[]` etc.)

So.  Be sure you indent your recipe lines with TAB characters and you'll be fine.  This is probably the single most common issue people have with makefiles.

Comment: Yup, you caught me there...there was another make file with M having the path details of the proj in a variable...deleted it, updated my query again but the problems seems to remain the same...i used tab= 4 spaces for both info and bsub

Comment: I would like to update that the spaces was the problem in my makefile...as the editor preferences were set to TAB = 4 spaces..it was not considering it a TAB...i used cat -e -t -v makefile_name to verify the spaces and tabs